# How to get absolute directory path from relative path + classloader

Tags: java, classloader, relative-path, resourcebundle, absolute-path

I have a class whose constructor receives a relative resources path (language properties files) and the corresponding classloader (the path is relative to the package of the classLoader):

```
public Language(String relDir, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    ...
}
```

Whithin that class I have a method that loads all found resource files (properties files such as MyFile_en_GB.properties), and it doesn't know whow many language resources there will be beforehand. It uses **languagesDir** as an absolute path for finding the resources.

```
private void loadLanguages() {
    DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = (path) -> {
      return Files.isRegularFile(path) & path.getFileName()toString().startsWith("MyFile");
    };
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(languagesDir, filter)) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
          String fileName = entry.getFilename().toString();
          ...
          loadPropertiesFile(filename)
        }
    } catch (..) {}
}
```

There, languagesDir works with an absolute path. However, when I tried:

```
String dir = classLoader.getResource(relDir).toString();
```

it throws an exception. I guess it is because it expects a file and not a directory

How can I get the absolute path of the resources? Should I try another aproach and work only with relative paths (how to do this)?

**edit:** About the exception:
`classLoader.getResource(relDir)` gives a null URL

Comment: `it throws an exception.` please edit your post and add the Exception.

Comment: Resources for a class loader are not necessarily files. They may be jar entries. You shouldn't try to manipulate resources using filesystem operations.

Answer (score 0):

try to use resourceFile.getName() after change URL to file.

```
URL resourceURL = classLoader.getResource(..);
File resourceFile = new File(new URL(resourceURL).toURI());
String fullPath = resourceFile.getName();
```

Comment: I get a null URL from the first instruction

Comment: of cource - you must use your resource - in your example dirPath + "\\" + fileName

Answer (score 0):

> it throws an exception. I guess it is because it expects a file and
>   not a directory

If that is the case you can feed files instead directory. To get the absolute path you try as below

```
       String dirPath = "C:\\Softwares";

        File dir = new File( dirPath );

        for ( String fileName : dir.list() ) {

            File file = new File( dirPath + "\\" + fileName );

            if ( file.isFile() ) {

                // System.out.println( file.getAbsolutePath() );
                String dir = classLoader.getResource( file.getAbsolutePath() ).toString();
            }
        }
```